# What is the difference between these two equations in regards to explicit solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm currently self-studying ODE's and am confused by what this statement means.

> $$
> \tag*{(3.41)}
> F(x, y, y', \cdots, y^{(n)}) = 0,
> $$
>   if
>   $$
> F[x, f(x), f'(x), \cdots, f^{(n)}(x)] = 0
> \tag*{(3.42)}
> $$
>   for *every* $x$ in $I$. ([Picture of the Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxbvj.png))

Aren't they the same? Can some explain in layman terms? Isn't $f(x)$ the same as $y$ in the second equation?

Comment: $y$ might be a function of $x$, i.e. $y=f(x)$.  But $y$ might also be a function of several variables, or unrelated to $x$, or both $x$ and $y$ might be functions of $t$.  With just a tiny snippet of equations it's impossible to tell.

Answer (score 1):

It would have been better to include more context than just this snippet, but it looks to me like this is part of a definition of "solution of a differential equation".  So: $F$ is a function of $n+2$ variables, defined on some domain $D \subseteq \mathbb R^{n+2}$, and we consider the differential equation
$$ F(x,y,\ldots,y^{(n)}) = 0 \tag{1}$$ If  $f$ is a function defined and $n$ times differentiable on the interval $I$, such that 
for all $x$ in that interval, $$F(x,f(x),\ldots,f^{(n)}(x)) = 0 $$
(which in particular requires $(x,f(x),\ldots,f^{(n)}(x))$ to be in $D$), then we say that $y = f(x)$ for $x \in I$ is a solution of the differential equation (1).

For example, I claim that $y = \sqrt{x+1}$ is a solution of the differential equation $(2x+2) y' - y = 0$ on the interval $I = (-1,\infty)$.  Here $F(x,y,y') = (2x+2) y' - y$, which is defined for all $x$ and $y$.  To verify it is a solution, you just check that $f(x) = \sqrt{x+1}$ is defined and differentiable on $I$, with derivative $f'(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+1}}$, and that $$F(x,f(x), f'(x)) = \frac{2x+2}{2\sqrt{x+1}} - \sqrt{x+1} = 0$$
for all $x \in I$.

Answer (score 0):

No, $f(x)$ is a number while $y$ is a function.

So, the first function $F$ take a number and $n$ functions as arguments, while the second one take $n+1$ numbers. The nature of the objects is very different (and using the same name for both is indeed confusing), even if both functions $F$ are closely related.